# java jdbc nested exception

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, client-server

I have created client-server gui calendar application in eclipse but it doesn't work. I have such a strange exception.. Can someone help me to solve it. As a server I used mysql and fat jar plugin for eclipse to make runnable jar file.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure dueto underlying exception:
```

**BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION**

```
java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused
```

**STACKTRACE:**

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at calendarapplication.gui.CalendarApplication.main(CalendarApplication.java:40)
```

**END NESTED EXCEPTION**

Last packet sent to the server was 2 ms ago.

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2847)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at calendarapplication.gui.CalendarApplication.main(CalendarApplication.java:40)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at calendarapplication.gui.CalendarApplication.main(CalendarApplication.java:63)
```

Regards,

Comment: how does your jdbc configuration look like? i mean, which server/port you are trying to connect to? from the stacktrace, it seems that you are trying to connect to a server that you have either no access or is not running mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Check your JDBC connection string to make sure you have correct port number. By default MySQL runs on 3306. You can verify it by using  >netstat -b  command

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your server (mysql) is not started at specified address and port.